# sortableJs drag and drop not working in angular

Tags: angular, drag-and-drop, sortablejs

I have been using sortableJs in my angular application to create a drag and drop column. 
I am using sortableJs version 1.9.0
But suddenly the drag and drop seems to be not working. 
Also it is not working in either chrome or IE. 
Is this because of any version changes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are using the new version of angular then refer to this package

https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-sortable